# How to make a Trello-like drag and drop board interface using Swift on IOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am fairly new to IOS(Iphone) Development using Swift and for my starting project, I want to make something very similar to Trello board but natively on IOS. I am wondering how can I create UIViews similar to "Boards" horizontally and embed it with ScrollView, also "Cards" that can be drag/drop on to different columns of "Boards". My Idea is to use Customized UITableView and make table sections as "Boards", table cells as "Cards". But how can I make it looks better like the one in Trello:

[image: Some visual clue here]

Or should I create the "Board" and "Card" in Nib? 
Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: Your question is very broad. Please review the How To Ask at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
Ideally include the code you have tried and the problems you have got with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are very many ways on how to do this but for a beginner this may be quite challenging.

Your question is very broad but using table view I would try to do the following:

1. Create a system of table views which works without dragging and ensure everything works correctly and your data source is tidy (produce a high quality code). Ensure the table view cells have automatic dimensions.
2. Modify your cells so they are placeholders for views. Basically have a method like `cell.setView(myCardView)`. The views should then be ported to separate XIB files or used as embedded view controllers. Ensure that setting a `nil` view on cell will create a placeholder cell (the one you see before you drop the card).
3. Add gesture recognizers to move cells, long press gesture should give you a nice touch where you will check states `begin` to grab and then `changed` whenever user moves his finger around. On grab you need to take the held view, add it as subview to view controller main view, convert its coordinates (`UIView` has methods for that) and animate its position to where the finger is. Also set `nil` to cell view. On change (user drags) simply reposition the view (without animations) to where the gesture position is.
4. Detect movements between cell position and table views while moving. You need to first check which table view you are in by checking horizontal position of the gesture recognizer (should be trivial). And then at which cell you are at by combining vertical position and table view visible cells (this one will prove a bit harder). If a table view is changed (from where it was) you need to remove the placeholder cell from previous table view and add it to a new table view. I a cell is swapped you need to reorder cells.
5. Once dropped, gesture ends or canceled you need to put the view into the placeholder cell. This should be reversed from picking it up; you need to convert the cell view frame to main view frame and animate the view frame to the one from cell. Then insert the view into cell without animations. Then update your data source so the card is in correct position.

This answer is very broad but it might give you enough to start and ask more specific questions if needed once you start your development.